# apache show me php5 but I have already install php7

Tags: apache2, php

I have installed php7 but phpinfo() show me php5

Console show me php -v

```
php -v
jaskaran@jaskaran-OptiPlex-3020:/etc$ php -v
PHP 7.1.0RC6 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0-dev, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.1.0RC6, Copyright (c) 1999-2016 , by Zend Technologies
```

---

```
phpinfo(); //output
PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20
```

In a php folder PHP 7.1

```
jaskaran@jaskaran-OptiPlex-3020:/etc$ cd php
php/        php5/       phpmyadmin/ 

jaskaran@jaskaran-OptiPlex-3020:/etc/php$ ls
5.5  5.6  7.0  7.1
```

Now can I move my php version in apache2 php5 to php7

Comment: Very probably, you have `libapache2-mod-php5` installed, and you need to install `libapache2-mod-php7.0` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Open a terminal

```
cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled 

sudo a2dismod php5

sudo rm php5.load

sudo rm php5.conf

sudo a2enmod php7.0

sudo ln -s php7.0.conf ../mods-available/php7.0.conf
sudo ln -s php7.0.load ../mods-available/php7.0.load

sudo a2enconf php7.0-cgi
sudo a2enconf php7.0-fpm

# do those commands only if the above didn't work out
sudo ln -s php7.0-cgi.conf ../conf-available/php7.0-cgi.conf
sudo ln -s php7.0-fpm.conf ../conf-available/php7.0-fpm.conf

sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: -1 unless you can explain why it is necessary to create the links manually.